# Modal W3.CSS conflita com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal, w3.css

Estou experimentando o [W3.CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/) em uma aplicação [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) que até então usava Bootstrap CSS.

Porém o modal do [W3.CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/) usa âncora para abrir, já o [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) interpreta as âncoras como rotas e redireciona para a [rota](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

Como tenho um *otherwise*, ele redireciona para o `/` e não abre o modal.
Se eu cadastrar uma rota para o modal, o [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) abre como uma página e não como modal.

Gostaria de orientação sobre como proceder neste caso.

Comment: Só uma coisa não entendi, pensei que o w3.css foi só CSS puro, os links quem define é você não é? Coloca um exemplo desse Modal.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o serviço `$AnchorScroll`. Exemplo de implementação:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    if($location.hash()) $anchorScroll();  
  });
});
```

Você pode então criar links contendo a rota e a âncora desejada, assim:

```
<a href="#/rota#ancora">Rota/Âncora</a>
```

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs)

Comment: Vou testar quando chegar em casa ou se der por aqui mesmo, ainda assim onde devo colocar? Pode ser abaixo do app.config(); ?

Comment: Consegui testar aqui rapidamente, mas ainda assim não funcionou...